# Handle notification bar folding when Activity still running

Tags: android, android-activity, android-notification-bar

Let's say we have a standard `MainActivity` that extends `Activity`.

It contains `onCreate` method that is fired every time when `Activity` goes on the top (start application, call it again when gone minimized..) - so we can know when user does something outside our application.

Is it possible in any way to check if user expands notification bar (there he enables GPS or screen rotation) and folds it back ?

In this case `onCreate` is not called because this `Activity` is still on the top of the  stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got it - symply:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if ( hasFocus ) {
        doSomething();
    }
}
```

solves it (also handles application menu, activities changing, etc - every focus changing).